# Case Statement - ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some help in my SQL script, it might be solved in other cases and I tried to apply it to my case, but no luck.

I have this big table "employee table" that contains all of the employee details employee_id, first_name, last_name, country(country_name), etc.
and I also have this table "country table" that contains country_code, country_name

I want to get the country_code from the other table.

The country column in the employee table may or may not have a value and
another condition is sometimes it has US or USA value that match to one value in the country table which is "US"

I have this script that I made already.
I joined the two tables below in my subquery CASE statement but I'm having this error:
"ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row"

```
Select distinct emp.employee_id, emp.first_name, emp.last_name
     , (select case
               WHEN emp.country = 'USA' then 'US'
               WHEN emp.country like '%' || c.country_name || '%' then c.country_code 
               ELSE 'US'
                END "COUNTRY_CODE" 
          from country c, employee emp
         WHERE  emp.country like '%' || c.country_name || '%'
       )
  from employee emp
;
```

I dunno how am I going to do it. Hoping somebody can help me, it would really mean a lot to me. Thanks!

Comment: What is `c`?...

Comment: Hi I'm really sorry, the FROM in the subquery was removed my bad. The C is the country table

Comment: You need to clean up your data and then add a foreign key constraint from employee to country. Only clean data goes into a database such as this.

Comment: Why do you use `employee` table in the subquery with only restriction by the country code? Use regular join instead of subquery

Answer (score 1):

How about skipping the subquery which - obviously - returns more than a single row?

```
select e.employee_id, 
  e.first_name,
  e.last_name,
  case when e.country in ('US', 'USA') then 'US'
       else c.country_code
  end country_code
from employee e left join country c on instr(e.country, c.country_name) > 0;
```

---

By the way, if you used `distinct`, perhaps you should've put it into the subquery. Also, you should've correlated subquerie's `country` to main querie's `employee`, not introduce yet another `employee` table.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your tips! It is now ok. I found a way to do it in the subquery, I can't put it in a single query because there will be a discrepancy in the data.

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad you made it.

Answer (score 1):

```
select emp.employee_id, emp.first_name, emp.last_name, c.country as "COUNTRY_CODE"
from 
employee emp 
left join country c on c.country = decode(emp.country, 'USA', 'US')
group by emp.employee_id, emp.first_name, emp.last_name, c.country ;
```

There is a decode function in Oracle that can convert USA to US. Convert the USA to US and then match to the country table. I could not understand why your query is using % (unless there are partial match you have to). Based on my knowledge, group by is better than using distinct.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your tips! It is now ok. I found a way to do it! Yes, there are partial match in the data that's why I added the %.